# Troubleshooting "Notice Undefined index: httponly - secure - domain"

Tags: magento-1.9, error-log

Noticed my log file had ballooned to 500MB, it appears that every time a page is loaded these errors are logged:

```
2014-11-13T13:29:05+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: httponly  in /home/SITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 96
2014-11-13T13:29:05+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: secure  in /home/SITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 98
2014-11-13T13:29:05+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: domain  in /home/SITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 100
```

Is this a known issue with Magento 1.9 ?

What steps do I need to perform the stop these from occurring?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is this a known issue with Magento 1.9 ?

No.

> What steps do I need to perform the stop these from occurring?

Fix your corehack.

This can't happen:

```
    app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php:87
    // session cookie params
    $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
        'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );

    if (!$cookieParams['httponly']) {
        unset($cookieParams['httponly']);
        if (!$cookieParams['secure']) {
            unset($cookieParams['secure']);
            if (!$cookieParams['domain']) {
                unset($cookieParams['domain']);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Genius! One of my developers had to have done that because I NEVER would modify in that way. THANK YOU :) Now my only questions is why they did that and what effect it will have.

Comment: this core hack (commenting out $cookieParams declaration) was in place on a codebase i inherited, someone somewhere must be recommending it as a fix for something related to cookies.

Comment: Just to add information to this for future references. Commenting out domain, secure, and httponly is usually one of the suggested fixes for when people are having trouble during the web install step on a local machine. More than likely the Dev forgot to uncomment it again after it worked.