# error while placing order

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to magento. I am using the default rwd theme while placing the order im getting this wierd error message

```
"There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later.
1. Action.php:saveOrderAction(418)-GBCustom_Checkout_OnepageController
2. Standard.php:dispatch(250)-Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action 
3. Front.php:match(172)-Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard 
4. App.php:dispatch(354)-Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front 
 5. Mage.php:run(694)-Mage_Core_Model_App 6. index.php:run(139)-Mage "
```

After error reporting:

```
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\rwd-qa\app\code\local\GBCustom\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php(201): mageCoreErrorHandler(2048, 'Non-static meth...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 201, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\rwd-qa\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): GBCustom_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\rwd-qa\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
 #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\rwd-qa\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
 #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\rwd-qa\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
 #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\rwd-qa\app\Mage.php(694): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
 #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\rwd-qa\index.php(144): Mage::run('', 'store')
 #7 {main}
```

Onepage Controller:

```
<?php
 public function savePaymentAction()
{  
    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {  
        return;
    }  
    try {
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) { 
            $this->_ajaxRedirectResponse();
            return;
        }  
        // set payment to quote
        $result = array();
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('payment', array());
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $quote=$session->getQuote();
        $total = $quote->getBaseSubtotal() + $quote->getShippingAddress()->getBaseShippingAmount(); 
        $paid_total= Mage::helper('payment')->getPaymentPaidTotal($quote);  // amount remaining is to pay  
        //same card can't be used twice
        if(isset($data['card_number']) && isset($data['card_pin']))
        {
            if(Mage::helper('payment')->isCardExists($quote,$data))  
            {
                $result['error'] = $this->__('You already paying with this card, Try another'); 
            } 
        }  
        if(!isset($result['error'])) { 
            if($paid_total==0){    
                Mage::helper('payment')->deletePaymentQuote($quote,$data['method']);
                $paid_total= Mage::helper('payment')->getPaymentPaidTotal($quote);  // amount remaining is to pay
                }
            /*
            if redem amount is not mentioned
            */
            if(!isset($data['amount_to_redem'])){ 
                /*
                amount is paid already then asign remaining amount
                */
                if($paid_total==-1){
                    $data['amount_to_redem']=$total; // if nothing is paid then asign total
                    }
                elseif($paid_total>0){ 
                    $data['amount_to_redem']=$paid_total; 
                }else{ 
                    $data['amount_to_redem']=$total;  
                }  
            }

            if($paid_total-$data['amount_to_redem']>=0 || $paid_total==-1) {  // if amount is not exceds  or not paid at all
                $result = $this->getOnepage()->savePayment($data);
                $paid_total= Mage::helper('payment')->getPaymentPaidTotal();
                if($paid_total==0){
                    $redirectUrl = $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getPayment()->getCheckoutRedirectUrl();
                    if (empty($result['error']) && !$redirectUrl) {  
                        $this->loadLayout('checkout_onepage_review');
                        $result['goto_section'] = 'review';
                        $result['update_section'] = array(
                        'name' => 'review',
                        'html' => $this->_getReviewHtml()
                        ); 
                    }  
                    if ($redirectUrl) {   
                        $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
                    }                   
                }else{
                    $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                    $result['update_section'] = array(
                    'name' => 'payment-method',
                    'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
                    );  
                }
            }else{
                $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                $result['update_section'] = array(
                'name' => 'payment-method',
                'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
                );  
                //  $result['error'] = $this->__('Unabale to pay you entered amount. Amount Exceed than actual amount');
                }
        }
    } catch (Mage_Payment_Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getFields()) {
            $result['fields'] = $e->getFields();
        }
        $result['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $result['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
        $result['error'] = $this->__('Unable to set Payment Method.'.$e->getMessage().'-'.$e->getTraceAsString());
    }
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
}

/**
* Create order action
*/
public function saveOrderAction()
{  
    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }
    $result = array();
    try {
        if ($requiredAgreements = Mage::helper('checkout')->getRequiredAgreementIds()) {  
            $postedAgreements = array_keys($this->getRequest()->getPost('agreement', array()));
            if ($diff = array_diff($requiredAgreements, $postedAgreements)) {    
                $result['success'] = false;
                $result['error'] = true;
                $result['error_messages'] = $this->__('Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the order.');
                $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
                return;
            }
        }

        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('payment', false)) {  
            $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getPayment()->importData($data);
        } 
        $this->getOnepage()->saveOrder();
        //$redirectUrl = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getRedirectUrl();
        $redirectUrl=Mage::helper('payment')->havePayment(); // gets custom redirect url
        $result['success'] = true;
        $result['error']   = false;
    } catch (Mage_Payment_Model_Info_Exception $e) {
        $message = $e->getMessage();
        if( !empty($message) ) {
            $result['error_messages'] = $message;
        }
        $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
        $result['update_section'] = array(
        'name' => 'payment-method',
        'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
        );
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
        Mage::helper('checkout')->sendPaymentFailedEmail($this->getOnepage()->getQuote(), $e->getMessage());
        $result['success'] = false;
        $result['error'] = true;
        $result['error_messages'] = $e->getMessage();

        if ($gotoSection = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getGotoSection()) {
            $result['goto_section'] = $gotoSection;
            $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->setGotoSection(null);
        }

        if ($updateSection = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getUpdateSection()) {
            if (isset($this->_sectionUpdateFunctions[$updateSection])) {
                $updateSectionFunction = $this->_sectionUpdateFunctions[$updateSection];
                $result['update_section'] = array(
                'name' => $updateSection,
                'html' => $this->$updateSectionFunction()
                );
            }
            $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->setUpdateSection(null);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
        Mage::helper('checkout')->sendPaymentFailedEmail($this->getOnepage()->getQuote(), $e->getMessage());
        $result['success']  = false;
        $result['error']    = true;
        $result['error_messages'] = $this->__('There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later.'.Mage::callStack(debug_backtrace()));
    }
    $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();
    /**
    * when there is redirect to third party, we don't want to save order yet.
    * we will save the order in return action.
    */
    if (isset($redirectUrl)) {           
        $result['redirect'] =  str_replace(Mage::getBaseUrl(),'',$redirectUrl);;
    }

    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
}
public function failureAction()
{
    $lastQuoteId = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getLastQuoteId();
    $lastOrderId = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getLastOrderId();

    if (!$lastQuoteId || !$lastOrderId) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();   
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->unsLastQuoteId();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->clear();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->unsLastRealOrderId();
}
/**
* Order success action
*/
public function successAction()
{
    $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
    if (!$session->getLastSuccessQuoteId()) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }

    $lastQuoteId = $session->getLastQuoteId();
    $lastOrderId = $session->getLastOrderId();
    $lastRecurringProfiles = $session->getLastRecurringProfileIds();
    if (!$lastQuoteId || (!$lastOrderId && empty($lastRecurringProfiles))) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }

    $session->clear();
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId)));
    $this->renderLayout();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->unsLastQuoteId();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->clear();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->unsLastRealOrderId();
}
```

}

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Enable magento and check what you get error wheneevr place an order

Comment: enable magento means?

Comment: Enable magento log

Comment: after enabling log im getting the above error

Comment: attach log when you have place an order

Comment: Update with new log..

Comment: share code GBCustom\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php

Comment: I guess that you did not put full code GBCustom\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php.Please put it code

Comment: This is the full code. In network tab im getting the error Strict Notice: Non-static method Mage::callStack() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context  in C:\xampp\htdocs\rwd-qa\app\code\local\GBCustom\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php on line 201

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34646/discussion-between-user3041822-and-amit-bera).

Answer (score 1):

It's a common mistake when developing in php.

The developer forgets to see if the array index exists before using it.
In your case, you must have a *httponly* array key at `C:\xampp\htdocs\rwd-qa\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php` on line 96.

It should be something like `$array['httponly']`, but this array key doesn't exists.

You can simply add the following line before this one:

```
$array['httponly'] = (isset($array['httponly']))?$array['httponly']:'';
```

Just replace $array for the corresponding variable name in your file.

Or you can see this other answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/43920/555).